# Firefox lineheight fail

Tags: css, firefox

Keeping the height of a textbox as uniform should seem like a simple task for browsers, right?

Apparently not.  If I go to http://liveonlinemath.com/workshops/ and look at the quote on the left starting with, "Being able to interact with..." it looks fine in Chrome (v. 39), but in FF (v. 34) the line spacing/height is different which causes a formatting issue toward the end of the quote.

I've attached this image for comparison's sake.  You may need to view it directly (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzRyO.jpg) because it appears to be shrunk down to fit in this post.

[image: Browser comparison]

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: try to add a `line-height: 12.5pt;` in the `div#e3` section of your `index_p.css`

Comment: try to add line height in 16px. not in pt.